# mongodb $lookup with findOne mode

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to join two mongodb collections, `collectionA` and `collectionB`.

For each document in `collectionA` I want to check if exists a coincidence in `collectionB`.

If I do it in a `$lookup`, it returns all the documents joined, but I would like the search in `collectionB` stops as soon as one coincidence ​is found (kind of a mongodb `findOne`). My concern is the performance, I know I could get just the element 0 from the array.

Is there a way to do it using the mongodB aggregation framework?

Example:

**collectionA:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "item": "almonds"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "item": "pecans"
  }
]
```

**colectionB**:

```
[
  {
    "_fid": 1,
    "date": "2021-01-10"
  },
  {
    "_fid": 1,
    "date": "2021-01-11"
  },
  {
    "_fid": 1,
    "date": "2021-01-12"
  },
  {
    "_fid": 2,
    "date": "2021-01-03"
  }
]
```

`$lookup` mongoDb

```
db.colectionA.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "colectionB",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_fid",
      "as": "matches"
    }
  }
])
```

*Result*

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "item": "almonds",
    "matches": [
      /* I don't want this array, with 1 element would be enough */
      {
        "_fid": 1,
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
        "date": "2021-01-10"
      },
      {
        "_fid": 1,
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
        "date": "2021-01-11"
      },
      {
        "_fid": 1,
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
        "date": "2021-01-12"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "item": "pecans",
    "matches": [
      {
        "_fid": 2,
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
        "date": "2021-01-03"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can test on this [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bow7AZWNBSk).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you're using at least MongoDB 3.6, you can [execute an aggregation pipeline on a joined collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection). It might look like this:

```
db.colectionA.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "colectionB",
      "as": "matches",
      "let": {
        "fid": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$_fid",
                "$$fid"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Working Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2HfT8BblmO3)

Comment: Thank you very much @Montgomery, it's an elegant option. Do yo know if `$limit: 1` stops the `$match` stage when one document is found? It's just what I want to achieve, kind of `exists` in traditional sql.

Comment: No, I don't believe so. The `$limit` stage operates on the results of the `$match` stage, so all matching documents get passed along and up to one will be returned.